# When does a color channel such as RGB carry more info than a grayscale channel or image?

Tags: signal-analysis, image-processing, power-spectral-density, spectrogram

Typically a gray-scale image gives us more information about an image in terms of a signal processing problem. But when does a color channel carry more info than a gray-scale channel?

I understand the use of FFT applied to gray-scale channels for this usual phenomena, but I want to know what is an instance of the opposite being true.

Comment: Let's say you generate a greyscale image from an RGB by defining it as average of the three color channels: $Y= \frac13(R + G+B)$. Now, lets have an image where the green channel always decreases in intensity when the red channel gains intensity (for example: picture of cherries getting ripe. They're either green or red.) Then, the sum will contain less information on the ripeness than the red channel alone. I found that example easy to come up with. Can you find another one?

Comment: RGB has three color channels. Do you mean just one of them (R, G, or B)?

Answer (score 1):

Define a greyscale picture as linear combination of its color channels¹.

Then your greyscale picture's entropy inherently is lower than a single color channel's entropy if there's an overall negative correlation between that single channel and the linear combination of the others. Entropy is the expectation of information.

> I understand the use of FFT applied to gray-scale channels for this usual phenomena, but I want to know what is an instance of the opposite being true.

The FFT doesn't have anything to do with this – it just transforms channels isolatedly from a spatial base to a spatial frequency base.

---

¹ not all color models work like that. We can still work with that and declare the nonlinearity an error...